# What method would you use to work out this question

Tags: probability

**Sometimes the street light outside my house works properly, but sometimes it is faulty. If
it works properly one day, there is a 95% chance that it will work properly the next day as
well. But if it is faulty one day, there is a 98% chance it will be faulty the next day as well.**

**On average, on how many days is it faulty each year? You should assume that a year is
exactly 365 days long. Show your working and explain your answer.**

At first I thought the method to work this out would be the Markov process but after second thoughts I don't think that will work here?

So what would be the method to solve question?

Comment: Is it good or bad on January $1$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm not sure it's not specified in the question

Comment: @AndréNicolas I don't think it needs to be specified.

Comment: For exact solution it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the probability that it is working on any given day. Probability for tomorrow:

- If it works today: $x*.95$
- If it doesn't work today: $(1-x)*.02$

Add disjoint probabilities for overall probability for tomorrow: $$x*.95+(1-x)*.02$$ but tomorrow's probability is the same as today's so $$x=x*.95+(1-x)*.02$$ isolate and solve for $x$.
$$x={2 \over 7}\approx .285714$$
It is working $${2 \over 7}365 \approx 104.2857$$ days of the year. So it is faulty $$365-104.2857=260.7143$$ days of the year.

Comment: Wouldn't this be the solution for how many days in a year it is working for?

Comment: Your right. I changed that now.

Comment: Also i ended up getting the same answer using the Markov process so thanks.

Comment: You could also post your Markov process as an answer if you want. I would find it interesting.